# org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: server-address:80 failed to respond - JMeter

Tags: java, testing, jmeter

I am running a load test using Jmeter 5.2 on a web application.
When I run the thread group even with a greater than  500 thread,
I do some configuration jmeter : 
in user.properties I have set :
 httpclient4.retrycount=1

hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters

In hc.parameters I have set:

http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true

and in Http request : client Implementation > httpClient4

```
 org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: server-address:80 failed to respond
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:850)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:561)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1282)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1271)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:627)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:551)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:490)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

any idea how to resolve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your application gets overloaded hence it cannot handle 500 concurrent connections, you need to check the following:

1. Your application server configuration, i.e. [increase maximum number of incoming connections](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/internet-core-protocols/1565925726/ch01s04.html)
2. Your backend health in terms of CPU, RAM, available network sockets, etc., it can be done using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)
3. Your application configuration ([connection pools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern), database configuration, etc.) as it might not be properly tuned for high loads

Comment: I checked the server configuration where I found that it is necessary to increase the maximum number of connections, the problem is related to TCP
Number of connections the client side :
`net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768 60999`
 `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 60 (60999 - 32768) / 60 = 470 sockets per second`
 The Server Side
`net.core.somaxconn = 128 `